# Creation of generic type using Spring Config

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How can I instantiate a bean with generic type using Spring config

```
public class GenericService<T> 
{
 ...
}
```

Note that T is not the concrete type of a bean property. It is really just the type for one of the methods of the service.

In other words..
Can I instantiate new GenericService of type `String` or new GenericService of type `Long` using Spring context.

My generic class contains

```java
public <T extends WordplayService> List<S> performTheService(String word, Class<T> clazz) 
{ 
    return clazz.newInstance().getAllWords(); 
    ...
}
```

The return type of the generic method depends on the concrete parameter type of the class instantiated. 
Is this possible or a wrong usage of DI + generics? TIA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generics are a compile-time concept, while spring context is loaded at runtime, so they don't intersect. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is your usecase.

Comment: Hi Bozho
I am just learning here. Can I instantiate
new GenericService<String>() or new GenericService<Long>() using spring context.
My generic class contains
    public <T extends WordplayService> List<S> performTheService(String word, Class<T> clazz)
    {
      try {
            return clazz.newInstance().getAllWords();
....    

The return type of the generic method depends on the concrete parameter type of the class instantiated.
Is this possible or a wrong usage of DI + generics?
TIA

Comment: You can safely use DI with generics, because as I said, generics are lost at the time when the dependencies are injected.

Comment: Thanks, That clarifies.
I did see that I can access generic type info at runtime using reflection. But it seems way too complex and is definitely not designed to inject beans with concrete types

Answer (score 3):

> You can safely use DI with generics, because as I said, generics are lost at the time when the dependencies are injected.
>
> Generics are a compile-time concept ...

The truth is, Generic information is not (completely) erased at compile time. You can still retrieve this information via reflection, and that is what the Spring DI container does already for collections. See 3.3.3.4.2. Strongly-typed collection (Java 5+ only) in 2.0.8 Spring documentation (sorry can only post one hyperlink).

However, I do not know (yet) if it is possible to instruct the container to do that for your custom classes as well.

If you want to know how to retrieve this information at runtime, here's the original post from Neal Gafter: http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Answer (score 1):

You should just instantiate it using the raw class name.  As @Bozho says generics are a compile-time only construct and their full types are not available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers shows any examples, its easy :

```
@Resource
private CommentService<String> stringCommentService;

@Resource
private CommentService<Integer> integerCommentService;

@Test
public void genericTest(){
    System.out.println("Generic test .... :");
    stringCommentService.printType("test");

    System.out.println("INT Generic test .... :");
    integerCommentService.printType(9);

}
```

Where commentservice looks like you'd imagine:

```
@Service
public class CommentService<T> {
```